# Can I delete the mwf_config file?

Tags: delete, ubuntu-mate

I found this file in `~/Documents` (not hidden), I opened the file in Pluma but found that it is blank so am I safe to delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way is to rename this *probably* harmless file:

```
mv -v ~/Documents/mwf_config ~/Documents/mwf_config_bak
```

Then 3 possible things could happen:

1. The file will be recreated: It is a necessary file...
2. An application will complain about a missing file: Then run:

   ```
   mv -v ~/Documents/mwf_config_bak ~/Documents/mwf_config
   ```
3. Nothing at all :)

If No. 3 is the case your file can safely be deleted...

Comment: I don't even want to see this file, so I will just rename it to .mwf_config_bak, thanks